# Time-dependent actions on multiple child objects

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a custom child object with Account as Master.
A flow sends a NPS survey to the child record-contact X hours after First_Transaction_Date__c

The thing is that several child record can have the same First_Transaction_Date__c, but in that case I only want to send one Survey.
Is there a way to do this with a Flow on the child object? I've tried setting a criteria that only sends the survey if the related Account has not been sent a survey yet, but when the First_Transaction_Date__c is the exact same for all child records, it doesn't work.

One work around would be to trigger the flow on the Account but first I'd like to see if there's something I'm missing to do this on with the flow on the child object.

Thanks in advance.
/Y

Comment: Is there any field to identify for which child records the Survey should be sent?

Comment: It should be sent once per Account 30 days after the First_Transaction_Date__c is populated on the child record. But there's no other filter.

Comment: So in flow you are using action called send survey to send the survey in asynchronous action?

Comment: Are you giving Subject as childobject or Parent object in survey action?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a field that identifies the *first* Child record with that specific First_Transaction_Date__c and Account lookup. And add that custom field to the criteria to send the NPS survey.

For instance if you named a checkbox Send_Survey__c that was stamped by a record triggered flow on creation, it could look for any other children with that same First_Transaction_Date__c and AccountId. If none are found then this is the first of its kind and warrants a Survey, setting the checkbox to true.

If some are found then the survey does not need to be sent from this child.

Finally, the flow that sends the NPS Survey must also check that the Send Survey checkbox is true.